# bootstrap4 dataTables search option is not working

Tags: jquery, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap4 dataTables for showing row limit & search options. I am using Ajax for populated data from server. Data is populated in dataTables but search option is & show row options is not working. here is my table images

[image]
I have used bellow code

1. HTML Code

   ```
   <table class="table table-bordered" id="tb_requisiton" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Std. ID</th>
           <th>Name</th>          
       </tr>
   </thead>        
   <tfoot>
     <tr>
       <th>Std. ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>                    
           </tr>
   </tfoot>
   </table>
   ```
2. Ajax populate code

   ```
     var trHTML = '';
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {              
         var item = data[i];       

         trHTML += '<tr>'
         trHTML += '<td>'+ item.client_id + '</td>'
         trHTML += '<td>'+ item.name + '</td>'           
         trHTML += '</tr>'                
       }

       $('#tb_requisiton tbody').append(trHTML);
   ```
3. Onload I have used bellow code

   ```
       $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#tb_requisiton').DataTable();

   } );
   ```
4. I have used bellow js & css

   ```
     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
   <script src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: As per the image, data is not populating correctly in the datatable

Comment: @JaiminRlogical data is populated correctly only filter option not working

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nsnrak

Answer (score 1):

Call the ajax inside the DataTable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tb_requisiton').DataTable({
        "ajax": 'data.txt'//ajax url
    });

});
```

Comment: Sir please help in my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66220981/datatable-filtering-with-select-option-is-not-working-in-php-ajax